How to upload data from a data logger to Google Drive?
I'm new to HTTP programming, and have been tasked with setting up a data logger to regularly upload the data it measures to a single folder on Google Drive or some other free cloud storage service.
My problem is that the data logger uses the CRBasic programming language, which is only capable of PUT, GET, and POST HTTP requests. Here's the PUT equivalent as an example: https://help.campbellsci.com/crbasic/cr300/#Instructions/httpput.htm#kanchor352. I can provide a URI and Header, but that appears to be it.
Most of the guides to the Google Drive API that I've read online seem to require the use of a higher programming language, which I can't do here. How can I connect to my Google Drive storage using this limited functionality?

Unfortunately, I cannot understand your situation. About My problem is that the data logger has a proprietary OS that appears to only support basic HTTP commands (PUT, GET, and POST). and the very basic OS, can you provide more information? What language do you want to use? If you want to use the access token, which do you want to use the OAuth2 or the service account? Also, about https://username:password@website_address, I think that this is the basic authorization. In the current stage, the basic filter cannot be used for Google APIs.

@Tanaike: My data logger uses the CRBasic programming language, which is capable of PUT, GET, and POST HTTP requests. Here's the PUT equivalent: https://help.campbellsci.com/crbasic/cr300/#Instructions/httpput.htm#kanchor352. I can provide a URI and Header, but that appears to be it. Is there any way that I can connect to Google Drive using these limited commands?

Thank you for replying. From your reply, I would like to recommend updating your question to help correctly understand your question.

Thank you for replying. When you can use GET and POST methods, I think that Web Apps created by Google Apps Script might be able to be used. Ref But, I have no environment for testing CRBasic. So, I cannot propose a clear answer including a sample script. I apologize for this.

Thanks @Tanaike. Would the Web App create a URL that I could use PUT to upload data?

Thank you for replying. About Would the Web App create a URL that I could use PUT to upload data?, unfortunately, in the current stage, Web Apps created by Google Apps Script can be requested with GET method and POST method. I apologize for this situation.
